# How can I store a reference table in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, data-structures

I am developing a simple calculator using jquery and html. To perform all the calculations needed, this calculator needs to reference a table of values formatted as follows:

```
Machine ID1
    6        52   5655
    7.5      55   2520
    10       60   1013

Machine ID2
    6        55    1255
    7.5      89    5655
    10       90    2020
```

Part of what this calculator does is it takes in a Machine ID, and it also takes in a row spacing (which can either be 6, 7.5, or 10) - i.e. the first column.

The second and third columns are values that are derived from the machine and row spacing.

My original plan was to create this calculator solely in jquery and HTML, but I am having a very difficult time figuring out how to implement this reference table in a data structure. These values in the reference table will not change, so I have no problem hard coding them into javascript.

I am aware I could use a database with the MachineID and the RowSpacing as the primary keys, but I feel like creating a new database with a single table that just contains the above info is overkill. What options do I have for storing the above data in jQuery that will allow me to query and pull the values?

I have investigated using jQuery's data functionality, but that seems to be more towards tying data to individual DOM elements, and I don't think that helps me much. Am I wrong? How can I make this work without a database?

Comment: Is the first value in each row the index used to do a lookup? Could you do something like `var table1 = { 6: [52, 5655], 7.5: [55, 2520], ... }` (and access like `table[6]`)? I'm finding it a little difficult to understand your requirements -- could you clarify what known value(s) are used to do a lookup and what values are fetched from a lookup? Are values fixed, or will you add new values/rows?

Comment: Sorry. I see how I could have phrased this problem differently. The MachineID and RowSpacing are known, and provided along with some other input. However, the values in the right two columns are static and will not change - they are reference values used in formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are static values, I think you'll be best served by storing them in a JSON object, like this:

```
var ID1 = {
    6 : {
        "value1": 52,
        "value2": 5655
    },
    7.5 : {
        "value1": 55,
        "value2": 2520
    },
    10 : {
        "value1": 60,
        "value2": 1013
    }
}

var ID2 = {
    6 : {
        "value1": 55,
        "value2": 1255
    },
    7.5 : {
        "value1": 89,
        "value2": 5655
    },
    10 : {
        "value1": 90,
        "value2": 2020
    }
}
```

This way, if you needed to refer to the machine name **ID2**, where row spacing is **10**, and get the second of your two values, you'd do it as follows:

```
Result = ID2[10]["value2"];
```

Comment: You nailed it. This is exactly what I need. Thank you!